# Why does this Tex refuse to compile?

Tags: errors

The following won't compile under pdfLaTeX, I'm thinking due to some sort of infinite loop error:

```
Comparing these spectral radiuses, we can say that the Gauss-Seidel method will converge
approximately $\log_{0.6978}0.3647 = 2.803$ times faster than the Jacobi method, and
that the Successive Over-Relaxation method will converge about $\log_{0.6978}0.2642 = 
3.699$ times as fast as the Jacobi method, and about $\log_{0.3647}0.2642 = 1.3196$
times faster than the Gauss-Seidel method.
```

This seems a little bit bizarre, why won't it compile?  I get the following error:

```
Package tocbibind Note: Using section or other style headings.

) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tocloft\tocloft.sty")
(C:\Users\Pete\Desktop\untitled-1.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsa.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd") [1{C:/ProgramData/Mi
KTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] [2])
*
```

Except it's not really an error, it just freezes there.

Comment: It compiles for me, but gives a bad box. May be you should provide more details! :)

Comment: Sorry, I edited it, tried simplifying it but failed a bit!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will show the error, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Do you have `amsmath`, `amssymb` packages in your preamable.

Comment: Also would help if you posted the error message that you got.

Comment: Have edited to include the error message. Sorry bit of a newbie at this.

Comment: @Peter: As egreg requested it is better if you make a [complete compilable example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Check to see if you forgot `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please provide your preamble and some dummy text. Try deleting all aux files and created files and recompile.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina - it's definitely there.

Comment: I don't think it's due to *that* paragraph. The final `*` means that TeX is unable to find correctly an ending command; do you have any `verbatim` things?

Comment: I agree with egreg; something is hiding the `\end{document}`; I proper MWE would be ideal here.

Comment: Perhaps if you copy-and-paste the entire text into a unicode-free editor and then back into your LaTeX editor. There may be some hidden characters causing the problem.